# Java Connect Database on Site

Tags: java, database

Hi guy i want to connect to my database on my website using java. i wonder what should i put in URL:

```
cnt=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_UID,DB_PWD);
```

Can you guy give me an example how to connect Mysql Database on website using java?

i have try to use:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class CreateConnect {


public final static String DB_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
public final static String SEVER_HOST="mysite";
public final static String PORT_NUM="3306";

public final static String DB_NAME="studentdb";
public final static String DB_UID="root";
public final static String DB_PWD="root";

public final static String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://"+SEVER_HOST+":"+PORT_NUM+"/"+DB_NAME;

private static Connection cnt;

public static Connection getConnection()
{

    try
    {

        cnt=DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_UID,DB_PWD);
        System.out.println("Connection Successfully");
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Connection ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cnt;
}
```

Comment: Then what is the error/exception ?

Comment: do u want to connect to database were u hosted ur website.am i right?

Comment: its usually `localhost:port/db_name`

Comment: Is it not problem that driver class is not loaded. I do not see use of DB_DRIVER. Something like Class.forName(DB_DRIVER) or it is done somewhere else? If you would like to use this code on web with many threads you can have problem.

Comment: in between u did not add `Class.forName()` for initializing the driver?

Comment: @Arun
you are right. i want to connect to database that i was upload on my hosted website.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I understood your problem but if you could tell me the error that would have been more helpful to debug.

Add this line before calling getConnection method.

```
Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
```

I hope it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

The below reference can help you connect to the database which is hosted.you have to provide the IPaddress of the site and port number `3306` to connect to the database.

[JDBC: connect to remote mySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18196032/jdbc-connect-to-remote-mysql-database)

Comment: port 3306 is used  in the code, SEVER_HOST should be changed to a real hostname of server running my sql

Comment: SERVER_HOST should contain the IP address of the host.

Comment: preciselly ip or DNS name (hostname) if DNS work on the server that runs the java code